# Filemaker JSON httpspost

Tags: json, api, filemaker

I am trying to use the plivo.com api with Filemaker to send SMS with my database.

I am using "insert from URL" to POST to the api, like below:

(ACCOUNTID, FROMNUMBER, and TONUMBER has been switched out)

httpspost://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/ACCOUNTID/Message/{"src":"FROMNUMBER", "dst":"TONUMBER", "text":"Testing text"}

The plivo site said something about using JSON for receiving, I had tested with other Filemaker solutions (FmSms) and confirm the functionality is working, so it has to be my post query is in the wrong format.

Would be great if someone of experience can give me some pointer in solving this issue.

[Linkage to Plivo's documentation regarding messaging](https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/message/)

Thanks in advance
Sunny

Comment: After verifying the answer: Note that the reason FMSMS is working might probably be due to them hosting a server to collect the data first then send via their server as json format to plivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work with FileMaker alone. The webservice accepts content-type `application/json`, FileMaker can send `x-www-form-urlencoded` only.

Comment: Thanks Jens! The information is very helpful. Now i guess i will find another service provider with the right api.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to use a web viewer with some javascript to handle the request and return data back to FileMaker. See the blog post here: http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2014/11/filemaker-and-javascript-ajax-post

Also, the free base elements plugin will allow you to set custom headers and should also work.